# while loop if and else

Tags: c++, if-statement, while-loop

What the code does is ask the user which card he wants and prints out a statement depending on which card is chosen.

My aim is to loop back to the card select function if numbers other than 1,2 and 3 are entered.

There is also a for loop which allows this process to go around multiple times.

What is the best way and how can I do this?

```
int CardSelect() {

  cout << "Enter 1 for hearts" << endl;
  cout << " " << endl;
  cout << "Enter 2 for diamonds" << endl;
  cout << " " << endl;
  cout << "Enter 3 for joker" << endl;

  return 0;
};

int main() {
  for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    CardSelect();
    int cardchoice;
    cin >> cardchoice;

    cardchoice = CardSelect();

    if (cardchoice == 1) {
      cout << "You got hearts" << endl;
      loop = false;
    } else if (cardchoice == 2) {
      cout << "You got diamonds" << endl;
      loop = false;
    } else if (cardchoice == 3) {
      cout << "You got joker" << endl;
      loop = false;
    } else {
      cout << "Invalid choice" << endl;
      cout << "Please ensure you type in the right numbers" << endl;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `CardSelect()` always returns zero so it won't do what it looks like you are trying for.

Comment: `CardSelect()` directly erases use input stored in `cardchoice`

Comment: any suggestions?

Comment: If you want to display those messages simply use a void type function. No point in returning anything if you just want to display something from the function.

Comment: @coder Whats the logic behind those `loop = false` statements in your main? Firstly there is no boolean / bool variable named loop, secondly if you want to break after an input why use the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change return type of `CardSelect()` to void, since your simply printing some statements in that function:

```cpp
void CardSelect() 
{ // Your cout statements
}
```

Call that in `main()`, and use a switch case for your `cardchoice` variable.

If you want to keep running the switch statement till you get a valid input, put everything in an inifinte loop (such as a `while(1)`) and set an exit condition by setting a boolean to true (set it to `false` initially) and using `break` when condition is satisified, to get out of the loop:

```cpp
int main() 
{
  while(1)
  {
    bool valid = false;
    CardSelect(); // call to your function
    int cardchoice;
    cin >> cardchoice;

    switch(cardchoice)
    {
      case 1:      
      cout << "You got hearts" << endl;
      valid = true;
      break;

      case 2:     
      cout << "You got diamonds" << endl;
      valid = true;
      break;

      case 3:    
      cout << "You got joker" << endl;
      valid = true;
      break;

      default:
      cout << "Invalid choice" << endl;
      cout << "Please ensure you type in the right numbers" << endl;
      break;
    } if(valid) break;
  }
}
```

Comment: this is a good example but one issue I face is that the for loop carries on going. This doesn't seem to work

Comment: If you don't have any subsequent code to run then simply use `exit(0);` inside the `default:` scope

Comment: Thanks for the help but it doesn't really loop if the wrong number is entered

Comment: @coder I don't understand what you want. Do you want to keep on continuing the loop till 5 times for different inputs of `cardchoice` (which may be a valid 1,2,3 or wrong input) or do you want to exit the for loop at the first wrong number, and not continue the for loop again?

Comment: lets say that there is no for loop. This will go around one time. If I was to enter 4 then it will say invalid choice and then call the cardselect function. Thats what im trying to achieve

Comment: @coder After saying invalid choice you want to enter the switch case again, is that it? (i.e. you want to keep going till you get a valid input) Or do you want to keep going till as many times as you want?

Comment: Thank you for being patient, it works the way I want it. I just have to learn more on this subject. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

First, what you are looking for is `continue`, second you need to get rid of this line which makes no sense : 
    `cardchoice = CardSelect();`
as it erases user input

```
int CardSelect() {
    cout << "Enter 1 for hearts" << endl;
    cout << " " << endl;
    cout << "Enter 2 for diamonds" << endl;
    cout << " " << endl;
    cout << "Enter 3 for joker" << endl;

    return 0;


};



int main() {

for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    CardSelect();
    int cardchoice;
    cin >> cardchoice;


    if (cardchoice == 1) {
        cout << "You got hearts" << endl;
    }

    else if (cardchoice == 2) {
        cout << "You got diamonds" << endl;

    }

    else if (cardchoice == 3) {
        cout << "You got joker" << endl;
    }

    else {
        cout << "Invalid choice" << endl;
        cout << "Please ensure you type in the right numbers" << endl;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: What purpose should `continue` have here? At least for the given code, there wouldn't be a difference in the outcome if  `continue` is present or not.

Comment: @t.niese yes you are right. I was thinking of removing it, but does it not increase code readability tho ? not sure edit : i think it doesn't

Comment: No it won't if you read `continue` then you assume, that there is some code following that should not be executed, but there is no code that would not be executed if `continue` is missing, so having `continue` there would lead to the assumption that something is missing in the code.

Answer (score 0):

you should not call `cardchoice = CardSelect();`.

This call is overwriting `cardchoice` with 0. Remove this call.

You print values to see what is happening. Its a good way of learning.
Hope this will help.